# Is Generator supposed to be lazy?

Tags: php

I tried to calculate the nth prime number in PHP:

```
function is_prime($n) {
    if ($n <= 1) {
        return false;
    } elseif ($n <= 3) {
        return true;
    } elseif (($n % 2 == 0) ||  ($n % 3 == 0)) {
        return false;
    }

    $i = 5;
    while ($i * $i <= $n) {
        if (($n % $i == 0) || ($n % ($i + 2) == 0)) {
            return false;
            $i = $i + 6;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function prime_gen() {
    for($x=0; $x< PHP_INT_MAX; $x++) {
        if(is_prime($x)){
            yield $x;
        }
    }
}


function nth_prime($n) {
    for($i=0; $i<=$n; $i++) {
        $ps = iterator_to_array(prime_gen());
    }

    return $ps[$n-1];
}

echo nth_prime(9);
```

I got `Maximum execution time of 3 seconds exceeded` error. Is generator supposed to be lazy? Shouldn't I write `for($x=0; $x< PHP_INT_MAX; $x++)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterator_to_array` iterates the *entire* generator until it is exhausted and gives you the result in an array. The *generator* is "lazy", but you're explicitly breaking that and are forcing the evaluation of the entire generator. Moreover, you're doing *that* in a loop. You pretty much just need to get rid of `iterator_to_array`. Better solution:

```
$nth = 0;
foreach (prime_gen() as $prime) {
    if (++$nth >= $n) {
        break;
    }
}

return $prime;
```